# Inputting values from .mat file to array in C++

Tags: c++, matlab

I am trying to copy a 1100x1100 matrix from a .mat file to an array variable of type **float** in C++. I read online and found that the **matio** library is a good option. I installed their library using "make" on Ubuntu 12.04 (I followed the method given on their webpage). 
However, I am unable to write code using it mainly because I am new to C++. I am using g++ to compile the file. I get errors such as "unknown reference to Mat_Open" and so on.
I did find this bit of code on the webpage:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "matio.h"
int main(int argc,char **argv)
{
    mat_t *matfp;
    matvar_t *matvar;
    matfp = Mat_Open(argv[1],MAT_ACC_RDONLY); //here argv[1] is "a.mat"?
    if ( NULL == matfp ) 
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"Error opening MAT file %s0,argv[1]);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    matvar = Mat_VarReadInfo(matfp,"x"); // x is the variable we are trying to access?
    if ( NULL == matvar ) 
    {
    fprintf(stderr,"Variable ’x’ not found, or error reading MAT file\n");
}
```

I have a couple of questions:

- here, **argv[1]** corresponds to the .mat file I am trying to open right?
- **x** in this code is the variable present in the .mat file I am trying to copy?
- When I ran this code, I received errors stating - Unknown reference to Mat_Open and so on. Another couple of the same type of errors also were there.

I compiled this using : `g++ abc.cpp -o test`. (Followed by `./test`. But I never got around to that due to the errors obtained during compilation).

How can I make it work? Is there any mistake with the code I used? Or with the compile statement I am using-maybe there are some linkers I need to use for compilation.

Thank you. Please remember that I am new to C++. Any advice would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

1) argv[1] - is a first parameter you put after your program call. If you want to "feel it", use debugger or code like this:

```
#include <iostream>
for (unsigned i = 0; i < argc; ++i)
{
    std::cout << argv[i] << std::endl;
}
```

2) Yes, looking at http://libmatio.sourcearchive.com/documentation/1.3.4/group__MAT_g4c8205ff25c5b688a40775fbb1840b7e.html I can say, that you will read variable with name "x".

3) "undefined reference" means you need to build with matio libraries. Add something like "-lLibraryName" to your compile string. And it will have to be built.

To avoid many problems, try to install Code::Blocks, it's cross-platform and quite easy to start using C++ if you never did it before. It also supports debuggers, so you will avoid many problems quite easy.

Comment: I will install CodeBlocks. But once I have it installed, where will I have to add library files and such? Also, I dont really understand what you mean by "first parameter you put after program call". I am familiar with C, and C++ seems to be very different indeed.
Also, where is the input .mat file being called?

Comment: Create new project. Add there all sources you need. In menu choose: Project -> Options. In open window choose "linker settings" to add library files, and "search directories" to set list of include directories with your headers.

Comment: Hello, where is the .mat file that is going to be input to the C++ program mentioned in the code above?

Comment: I have installed Code::Blocks and ran the code written above. I still get 2 errors:
undefined reference to Mat_Open and Mat_VarReadInfo. I couldn't find the library files in the folder I downloaded and unzipped from the sourceforge webpage for matio-1.5.2. How should I proceed next?

Comment: After you will build your program, for example, "testprog", you will need to start it by "testprog path/to/my/mat/file.mat", and then "path/to/my/mat/file.mat" will be received from argv[1] in your program. So, name of .mat file have to be parameter of your program that you will get from argv[i].

Comment: I don't know, if you downloaded binaries, you just need to find there library and use path to it in CodeBlocks. If you downloaded sources, you need to build them first, to get your library. Isially to build them under Linux you need to enter folder and type "./configure", then "make", then "make install". Or read manual inside folder with sources, usually there exists instruction.

Comment: I did the "make" and "make install" part once I downloaded the library. After doing so, where will the lib files be?

Comment: Best google that. Also you can get that info from makefile. And search folder with sources, on Windows it will be somewhere inside that folder. In subfolder with name "libs"/"bin"/something same. If on linux it moves binaries somewhere else, you can find path in makefile.

Comment: Will get back to you regarding that.

Comment: Any way by which i can find out where the library is?

Comment: Check in makefile section "install:"